# Cannot find the shape tool button

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm learning AI by following [this video](https://youtu.be/Ib8UBwu3yGA?t=3274).

However, I cannot find the shape tool button of the video on my left.

I have much less buttons than in the video.

[image]

[image]

Could anyone help?

Comment: Shape**builder** Tool.. It's there.. Below the Eraser Tool and above the Gradient Tool. 10th from the top

Comment: I see, but why I have less buttons than in the video?

Comment: I don't know... could be a smaller screen, different Workspace.. customized toolbar...

Comment: change your workspace to essentials classic

Comment: Note that the tutorial you are following is from 2 years ago. So, you are likely using a different version of Illustrator from the one shown, because the software gets updates almost every year. You can customize the toolbar.  See those three little dots under the tool bar, click them and it will let you customize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solution to bring it back

1 - You click on the 3 dots of your tool bar you can bring back by click and drop to your toolbar

2 - Go to Window > Toolbars > Advanced